# Making shebang dynamic in PHP CLI scripts

Tags: php

I wonder if is there any way to make shebang value on the top of my PHP CLI files dynamic (being set as a constant on a config file)?

Is there any one who had an experience about this before?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this answers your question, but:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

should work almost everywhere

Answer (score 3):

Use a symbolic link. That's typically the way unix remaps the location of the interpreter. (whether it's bash, perl, python, php...)

http://www.linux.org/lessons/advanced/x1110.html